# Creating h5py.Datatype objects using h5py

Tags: hdf5, h5py

How do I create a `Datatype` element in a file using *h5py*?

I'm trying to copy elements of an HDF5 file to another file in order to just capture a small subset of the elements.  I can get the `Dataset` and `Group` elements, but I'm having difficulty copying over the `Datatype` elements.

```
outFile.create_dataset(dataSetName, (400, 2, 10), data=dataGroups[:400,:,:10])  # success!!!
typeGroup = outFile.create_group('Types')  # success!!!

outfile['myDataType'] = inFile['myDataType']  # fail
# what's the magic call to create a Datatype object - there's no create_datatype()
```

And, by `Datatype`, one of these elements as displayed in *HDFView*.

[image: HDF5 Datatype]

Comment: Show your code.  Tell us the specific, exact problem you are having, with full, complete error messages.  Not "I'm having difficulty."

Comment: In your code you tag a line with '# fail`. Please be more specific an include the exact error message that you get.

Comment: Perhaps you can use the [low-level API](http://api.h5py.org/) of h5py to copy the type. The [H5T module](http://api.h5py.org/h5t.html) looks promising (disclaimer: I've never used it).